# Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 m broken css (like it's not loading completely)

Tags: css, google-chrome, overriding, stylesheet

I'm a programmer for an online store so i visit hourly this website. One of my coworkers said to me that for her the website looks awful so i instantly tried on my pc. It worked great but now after 1 day, i updated my chrome too and it looks awful.
I realized the chrome version 28.0.1500.71 m is messing the website. I don't know what exactly but something with the styles. It's like they don't load or something (part of the style is not loading or something because some elements have styles some not... and it's a real mess).

I checked on multiple PCs, different OS's: windows 7 (64 and 32), windows xp (on 3 different pcs) (when i had the older chrome version all worked wonderfully but now, when we all updated it looks very broken)...

I tried on ie 8, 9, 10, firefox, opera, safari and they all work superb, like they have to but, on chrome version 28.0.1500.71, is not.

What can i do? It's not like it's my fault or something but how can i change so it looks right again?

Please visit this page and tell me how do you see it and please verify it with chrome version 28.0.1500.71 and with another browser to see the difference.

*LINK REMOVED 2018 :) not needed anymore*

---

**Update:**

I'll keep you updated on what i do so you don't have to try again but for now i uninstalled google chrome version 28.0.1500.71 m and installed google chrome version 27.0.1453.116 m to be sure this is the problem. What do you think guys? It fixed the problem. But, i want a fix for version 28.0.1500.71 m.

**Update 14:44**

Ill update chrome back to 28.0.1500.71 m to make screenshots so everyone can see but first i'll make some screenshots in this version i have now (27.0.1453.116 m)

**Screenshots**

good) chrome 27.0.1453.116 m i.imgur.com/bWfvwdk.jpg

problem) chrome 28.0.1500.71 i.imgur.com/bx6ttRB.jpg

problem) chrome 28.0.1500.71 incognito i.imgur.com/76NUyOn.jpg

good) Latest opera i.imgur.com/gqWd6OT.jpg

good) latest firefox i.imgur.com/ImTVtSI.jpg

good) ie 10 i.imgur.com/FwvZy5j.jpg

good) IE 9 (browser mode IE9) i.imgur.com/74bTmGR.jpg

good) IE8 (browser mode IE8) i.imgur.com/KKqE997.jpg

good) Safari i.imgur.com/qWI0Wos.jpg

Comment: Are you using a lot of webkit-specific code? Chrome now uses Blink and not Webkit.

Comment: I use Chrome Canary and it looks perfect for me. Weird issue.

Comment: yea it does look weird, i dont think you could be such bad designer, not sure about programming skills,,, try to scrape, are u using a front end framework?

Comment: @Zenith thank you for the heads up i'll try to see if this is the problem @ BeatAlex indeed, weird :( @ Gunr Jesra The design looks good, i have 14 or more years in programming and i created everything but this kind of problem is gotta be the first i don't know what the fk, can be solved.

Comment: Thank you all especially to @Zenith Indeed the webkit done the trick. Ill post in the original post the solution. Thank you again.

Comment: @AbabeiAlexandru You should post it as an answer - It may help others in the future! :)

Comment: Didn't know about that :) i have this account for a year and 8 months but i don't use stackoverflow that often. so, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

**Big big thanks to @Zenith
He sayd that google chrome changed the webkit so i analysed the css and found**

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: .5;
    };
}
```

**I just removed it. Now it works perfectly. Thank you.**